# What is MikTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex

I want to learn LaTeX.  I was looking for some form of  software when I found them at
http://miktex.org/

It seems like it is free.  They say easy to download.

However, I don’t usually do stuff like this.  Is the download an independent LaTeX  program,  like Waterloo Maple ("plug-in-play")?  Is this what people here use?     Please forgive my naivety...  If this is the wrong forum for such questions please re-direct.

I  would, just,  hate to have to restore my computer on some experiment.

EDIT:  SamSung laptop.  About 2 years old.   Windows 7 Professional

Comment: how you get started might depend on your OS.  For Macs, there's MacTeX.  For Windows you can use MiKTeX.  For Linux, I'm not really sure what's available (I haven't had a Linux box for quite a while).

Comment: Try TeXlive. As for editors, I recommend you to try kile. BTW, if you would say what OS do you use, it would be much easy to answer you.

Comment: @Eddy_Em MikTeX is Windows-only.  Ergo no kile (not easily).  MikTeX is the best solution for a beginning user in LaTeX (especially a nervous one).  (I just realized I made quite the inference, but OP probably found MikTeX by a google search of `latex windows`.  Just a guess.)

Comment: Oh! And [welcome to TeX.SX!!!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436)  (By the way, the maker of your laptop *probably* isn't relevant, especially in this context. ;)

Comment: Please change your topic title and make it represent a question.

Comment: Start with [latex-doc-pointer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-doc-ptr/latex-doc-ptr.pdf) and [first-doc in latex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/first-latex-doc/first-latex-doc.pdf). See [Texlive and Miktex distro features](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/15717). Please refer to [faq section of tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Possibly related [How do I install TeX/LaTeX on Windows 7](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41808/15717) and [Answer by Stefan Kottwitz to "How do I get started with LaTeX on Windows XP?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1710/15717)

Comment: May be title can be changed to **What are the TeX/LaTeX distributions on different platforms ?** to cater for larger audience and newcomers. Of course there is [TeX collection DVD](http://tug.org/texcollection/texcollection2012.pdf)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a brief answer to your question:

- MikTeX is [absolutely free](http://miktex.org/copying), and the majority of it is [free as in speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#Libre).
- It is a straightforward installation and should be relatively familiar to you if you've installed programs before.  Normally you need administrator privileges to install MikTeX, but there is a [portable version](http://miktex.org/portable) available which has no such restriction, and can even be installed on a flash drive.
- LaTeX itself is not *strictly* stand-alone, but everything you need is included in MikTeX.
- MikTeX is one of the more popular distributions of TeX for Windows, but others exist (see below).  Usually, it doesn't matter what distribution you use; `TeX` is `TeX` wherever you get it.
- We on TeX.SX collectively use [many different variations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36) on Donald Knuth's original TeX, although many of us stick to the one that we prefer instead of switching back and forth.

---

## Preamble: What exactly is LaTeX/MikTeX?

Using LaTeX means you write some text combined with some strange command structure. This can be done either in Notepad or your favorite editor `<Censored to repel nerds>` and that would be basically your `.tex` file.

Then you feed this file into a TeX compiler and TeX starts to understand what you mean via interpreting the commands in the `.tex` file. There are a couple of options for the end product; some produce a `.ps` file some directly a `.pdf` file (or `.dvi` but let's forget about that for a second)

Now MikTeX is the collection of packages and the engines that receives your `.tex` file and produces some output. On Windows it's kind of the common choice. TeXLive and MacTeX are other major distributions for different operating systems; TeX Live is cross-platform, where MacTeX is for OSX.

Also there are some editors that allows you to type `.tex` files and when you press a button, or if you feel hip, a shortcut the editor sends your file to MikTeX for compilation automatically. The most popular choices (for Windows) are TeXnicCenter, WinEdt, TeXworks, etc. See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) for more options.

---

## What is a TeX distribution?

Regarding MikTeX, first and foremost, it (and almost *all* software having to do directly with LaTeX) is absolutely free - it is open-source.  It is very unlikely that you will have to restore your computer after installing MikTeX - almost as unlikely as having to restore it after downloading a paper.  Just be sure to follow all your normal installation dos and don'ts: try not to let the power die while you're installing it.

More technically, MikTeX is what is called a *TeX distribution* - it is a bundle of programs and files that are commonly used when working with TeX and its many derivatives, of which LaTeX is the most popular.  MikTeX includes, among many other things, the actual `latex` program.  It is a standalone piece of software that you can use either from command line or from a graphical interface such as TeXWorks (which is also included in MikTeX).

So with MikTeX, you get

1. An editor made specifically for editing LaTeX source files (TeXworks),
2. `latex` (+friends) to actually process your document into something share-able,
3. Yap, which is to `.dvi` files as your favorite PDF viewer is to, well, PDF files,
4. A fairly good GUI for a package manager, which helps you download packages (plugins, essentially) written in LaTeX for LaTeX (for the most part), and
5. A settings manager for the nerds.

A TeX distribution is thus designed to be a complete 'starter kit' for working with TeX, but there are differences between different TeX distributions.  For example, MikTeX is somewhat easier to set up than TeX Live, another distribution mentioned in the comments.  However, choosing MikTeX comes with a few obscure security issues, as described in [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/), but you are unlikely to come across these (and almost sure to never come across them if you're using it for yourself).  Installing and working with TeXLive is a separate topic, but more information can be found on [TeX Live's webpage](http://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html).

---

## Learning More

As far as learning LaTeX itself, there are countless resources available for free on the internet.  Among the highly recommended are

- David Wilken's [Getting Started with LaTeX](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/) is a wonderful introduction and has a nice [offline version (PDF, made with LaTeX)](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/GSWLaTeX.pdf) that is ideal as a desktop resource
- The [LaTeX WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a phenomenal resource for a broad introduction to LaTeX
- The introduction to LaTeX available on [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-doc-ptr/latex-doc-ptr.pdf) (the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network)
- A [first document in LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/first-latex-doc/first-latex-doc.pdf)
- A long and growing list of other online resources is available in [What are other good resources on-line for information about TeX, LaTeX and friends?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162)

Of course, there are excellent printed-and-bound guides and manuals available as well, including

- Leslie Lamport's seminal [LaTeX: A Document Preparation System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201529831)  (He literally puts the 'La' in 'LaTeX.')
- [The LaTeX Beginner's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847199860) by our own Stefan Kottwitz, an extremely handy desktop resource

---

Since you're new to this site, I would recommend checking out the [About](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about) page and [The Unofficial TeX-SX FAQ](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1144); these will give you a *far* better introduction to TeX.SX.  Of course, if you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask (but do be sure to use the search feature first!).

Good luck!

Comment: Not sure I would agree with MikTeX being easier to set up than TeXLive. The BIG advantage to TeXLive is that once you download it you have _all_ the packages and won't be caught offline needing some package.  Disk space is so cheap especially when we are only talking about a one time hit of a few GB that I don't see the fact that MiKTeX only downloads packages as needed being of _any_ benefit.

Comment: I've always installed MikTeX as one huge package... I've never been caught with an issue when I'm offline.  TeXLive has a similar 'basic' installation as MikTeX does; it's all about choosing the right one for your circumstance.  I would say the big advantage to TeX Live is *portability*: it's always the same.  But alas, I don't have a ton of experience with TeX Live as a distribution, per se.

Comment: I included it because I have (on more than one occasion) tried to switch to TeX Live to ease the back-and-forth between machines.  It didn't end well at all.  MikTeX has an idiomatic install and good tools that come with it - I see no need to tell OP that he should go find a better, more powerful, more portable distribution.

Comment: I agree with @SeanAllred, I have never had an issue with MikTeX when it came to packages. All I had to do was add it at the top and it would run.

Comment: Bouncing off of what @gekkostate said, MikTeX has a place with those who want to completely drown out the console origins of LaTeX; seeing that blinker on an all-text background can be daunting enough in itself for a new user.  It's much more 'user friendly,' in my most humble opinion.

Comment: @SeanAllred I've added more intro info but please feel free to spread out those details if you don't like the structure.

Comment: @percusse It's CW for a very good reason - I'm pessimistic about my own authoring abilities.  It's a very nice introduction, and one that I think is important here.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Fair enough. Perhaps I choose the wrong one to install with MikTeX and lucked out with the "correct" choice with TeXLive. But, in my experience (and do admit that I did not spend much time to try to figure out the problem), MikTeX was trying to re-download the same package every time (think it had to do with installing as admin, and not running as admin or some other combination). But since TeXLive works for me on both on Mac and PC I am very happy with it.

Comment: @PeterGrill that is very strange indeed.  I would also call TeX Live the 'correct' choice - if not for the reasons linked above, then simply for its cross-platform availability, as you mention.

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed and for the many helper links too.  I downloaded from the MikteX and received something called TeXworks and something else called yap.  What’s Yap?    So far, Using only the help feature,  I was able to type out completely one typical Eigen value problem (mathematics) on a pdf.   I didn’t expect that. However, as one might expect, i now have many more questions.

Comment: Luckily, many more answers exist on this site.  I'll edit some details on viewers into the answer, but TeXworks is already explained.

Comment: @dssmith Like we said in the answer, invest some time and skim through the LaTeX WikiBook.  It's well worth it, and will likely answer any questions you have at this stage.