# How do you really start?

Tags: tutorials

I was asked to use LaTeX (on [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)), and I downloaded a large number of files (called Miktex).

However all the tutorials seem to assume that you have already started a a document of some sort.

Where is that document?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Best Way to Start Using LaTeX/TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/5764)

Comment: Did they ask you to use latex to make _a document_ or to use the latex syntax _on math.stackexchange_ in order to show math on the website (using MathJax) these are _very_ different things.

Comment: Please take a look at the provided link above and see whether it suits your needs. It provides a host of ideas around starting with (La)TeX. If it does, we can close this question as a duplicate. If it doesn't, [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/116914/edit) and update it to reflect why it is different from the linked post.

Comment: Another question that might be helpful/a duplicate: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11)

Comment: Just to be simple: You need **1.** TeX distribution: [MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107601/15717) installed. **2.** LaTeX Editor:[TeXworks](https://texworks.googlecode.com/files/TeXworks-setup-0.4.5-r1281.exe). For one stop solution [`proTeXt`:easy to install MiKTeX distribution](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/windows/protext/). **3.** Verify TeX installation by typing at [command window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Command_Prompt.png) `pdflatex sample2e` to see `sample2.pdf` generated. **4.** [follow simple tutorial](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/absolute_beginners)

Answer (score 2):

Miktex holds your packages for compiling LaTeX documents.  You can either write you `.tex` files in a plain tex editor or from programs such as Emacs, Vim, Texnic Center, etc [list of tex editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).  You need to start a document called `name.tex` in either one of those programs or a plain tex editor.

Now you are ready write a LaTeX document.  At this point, you set up what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{packages you will use to compile your file(this what miktex has)}
\begin{document}
body
\end{document}
```

Here is my preamble as an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, eucal, pxfonts, setspace, enumerate, amscd,           
  dsfont, wasysym, tikz, tikz-qtree, mathtools, kurier, pgfplots, listings,         
  etoolbox, tikz-3dplot, float, wrapfig, multirow, array, tkz-fct, graphicx,        
  datetime, fancyhdr, amsfonts, xcolor, microtype, marvosym,       
  starfont}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```

Annotations:

11pt is the size of the font

dvipsnames allow you use extended color names such as Cyan, Aquamarine, etc

The tikz and pgf packages are need for creating graphics so that doesn't need to be a standard setup

wasysym, starfont, marvosym produce symbols for planets so this isn't a package that needs to be loaded unless you are working in orbital mechanics or aero engineering.

enumerate is useful for numbering since the program will keep track for you when you use `\item`

Comment: You should be ready for questions like: Why do you load [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) *and* [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)? `mathtools` loads `amsmath` by default. Why load [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) *and* [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color)? `xcolor` loads `color` by default... Also, is this your preamble for *everything* you use? What about [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) over [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)? Why do you load [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) so [early](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)? ...

Comment: @Werner not for everything.  I load enumerate over enumitem do to a question that David Carlisle helped resolved with numberings.  I didn't know xcolor loaded color so I can make that correction now.  I haven't noticed any issues with that placement of hyperref but I am not opposed to moving it.

Comment: @dustin: For `hyperref`-related loading dependencies, see [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Comment: I have edited the name.txt but what happens next?

Comment: The reason for asking these questions is based on the original post. A newbie without knowledge of (La)TeX sees your answer and assumes it's the correct way of starting *every* document, and therefore loads things as is. However, it's perhaps not optimal, nor would it suit the needs of everyone. Sure you mention it as "an example", but you should at least explain this in more detail so the OP can understand. For example, what's `11pt,dvipsnames` doing in your example when it's not included in your "basic structure"?

Comment: I assume I should activate some program to get started, the name.txt doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: @user31517 You have to run `pdflatex`; typically there is an editor button or shortcut for this. This will create a PDF document from your `.tex` file.

Comment: I couldn't paste directly to a file edited by the dos editor so I tried a word file which I later saved in .txt form. I found the pdflatex which opens a black window, but i don't know what to do with that. I assume that sowhere there is a more advanced and hopefully userfriendly editor.

Comment: @user31517 the file needs to be saved as `.tex` does your dos editor not support this?  If it does, can you do latex to pdf with a dos editor?  If the answer are no, you will need to get an editor that supports this file type and compilation.

Comment: I think that is what I need, where could I get it?

Comment: @user31517 look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) to find one that you may like.

Comment: @Werner I tested one of my files and if I only load `mathtools` without `amsmath`, it wont compile so I need both.  How can that be if `mathtools` is supposed to improve on `amsmath`?

Comment: @user31517 don't just try the first one.  There is a whole list.  Read about them before you pick one.

Comment: @dustin For a first time user,the preamble above is more overwhelming and **Note:** Although `\usepackage{bunch of list} works`, it will be difficult when you have to debug during errors and package conflicts hack down or hackup for a MWE creation. It is not recommended practice in my view.

Comment: @texenthusiast you are more than welcome to edit the preamble and make it simpler for a first time user.  I really don't know what the user will need as for packages.

Comment: @dustin: The line `\RequirePackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18]` inside [`mathtools.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.dtx) leads me to believe that you're doing something else as well.

Comment: @dustin Is it possible to cleanup the comments and absorb the knowledge via comments inside answer to keep Q & A nice and standalone. I prefer not to edit any answer too much except a few tweaks unless it's community wiki. I have left a comment to OP in any case.