# TexMaker 4.5 version does not run Quick Build and gives error message

Tags: compiling, texmaker, windows

I have just downloaded and installed TeXmaker 4.5 version on my new laptop (Windows 10). When I try to run Quick Build (Key F1), I get the error message:

```
"Could not start the command. pdflatex-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode%.tex".
```

On my old laptop (Vista) I have TeXmaker 3.5.2 version, and as I remember, I never had any problems with Quick Build since I installed it 6 years ago. I just press F1, F6, F7 to view a PDF file.

I haven't got a clue about the internal structure of LaTeX, so any straightforward guidance how to get it running properly on my new machine would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you install a TeX distribution?

Comment: I have never heard of Tex distribution before. Something like Tex Live? Obviously (If I remember correctly) I never needed it to run Texmaker 3.5.2 (I installed it before 2009 if it makes any difference).  @Bernard

Comment: @Alex TexMaker is only an editor, you will need a compiler,packges...etc and file they comes with. you may need to read a starter to Latex http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1706/92620 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107599/92620

Comment: Ok, so the TexMaker does not come with a compiler already? MikTex acts as a compiler and then should be synchronised with TexMaker, right? @SAM

Comment: @Alex: Yes. As far as I know it's better to install MiKTeX (or TeX Live) *before* TeXmaker.

Comment: yes TexMaker is only an editor which calls appropriate binaries (provided by a Tex distribution of course) during compilation.