# latex editors and installation for asus eeebook running windows 10

Tags: installing, editors

I recently got an asus e200ha netbook (config: Intel Atom Z8300, 2GB RAM and 32GB memory). What is a good light weight latex installation that I can install with this configuration? I'd also appreciate recommendations for a light weight latex editor.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1706/73

Comment: Note there's nothing particular about your system that makes the question distinct from the general ones before: you want a TX system and editor on Windows.

Comment: @JosephWright Well, there is a small difference: The netbook contains an atom processor as described by the OP, which means little computing power. Therefore it makes sense to ask for *light weight* programs.